# Cannot find the error in my code: ";expected"

Tags: syntax, if-statement

When i'm running the code it says that there's an syntax error and it marks me the else: Fatal: Syntax Error, ;expected but ELSE found.(btw this is just one part from my program) can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?

```
If D>0 then
   begin
       x1:=(-b)+sqrt(D)/(2*a);
       x2:=(-b)-sqrt(D)/(2*a);
       Writeln(x1,x2);
   else
      if D=0 then
   begin
       x:=(-b)/(2*a);
       Writeln(x);
   end;
```

Comment: Language at least? We're not magic language compilers :)

Comment: sure, that in this language "else if" is used and not elseif or elsif or just a second else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
If D>0 then
   begin
       x1:=(-b)+sqrt(D)/(2*a);
       x2:=(-b)-sqrt(D)/(2*a);
       Writeln(x1,x2);
   end
   else
      if D=0 then
   begin
       x:=(-b)/(2*a);
       Writeln(x);
   end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need one more `end;` tag as you have two `if begin` statements

```
If D>0 then
   begin
       x1:=(-b)+sqrt(D)/(2*a);
       x2:=(-b)-sqrt(D)/(2*a);
       Writeln(x1,x2);
   end
   else
      if D=0 then
   begin
       x:=(-b)/(2*a);
       Writeln(x);
   end;
```